# Reading Key value pairs of a JSON File

Tags: json, python-2.7

My code is as follows: The JSON File is https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwqfqb27blxr1bj/citiesclimate_2014_03_27.json

A small sample:

```
[ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5333d7e18828169279d9250d" },
    "actions" : null,
    "actions_nr" : 0,
    "city" : "Adachi City",
    "citylink" : "<a href=\"/data/report/commitments/?tx_datareport_pi1%5Buid%5D=198\" target=\"_blank\" >Adachi City</a>",
    "commitments" : "338,339",
    "commitments_nr" : 1,
    "country" : "Japan",
    "latitude" : "35.465",
    "longitude" : "139.482",
    "performance" : "355,356,1090,1091",
    "performance_nr" : 4,
    "uid" : "198"
  },
  { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5333d7e18828169279d92511" },
    "test" : [ { "actions" : null,
          "actions_nr" : 0,
          "city" : "Adachi City",
          "citylink" : "<a href=\"/data/report/commitments/?tx_datareport_pi1%5Buid%5D=198\" target=\"_blank\" >Adachi City</a>",
          "commitments" : "338,339",
          "commitments_nr" : 1,
          "country" : "Japan",
          "latitude" : "35.465",
          "longitude" : "139.482",
          "performance" : "355,356,1090,1091",
          "performance_nr" : 4,
          "uid" : "198"
        },
        { "actions" : "3025,3105,3106,3108,3109,3110,3111,3112,3113,3114,3115,3116,3164,3166,3167,3168,3170,3171,3172,3173,3174,3175,3176,3177,3180,3181,3182,3183,3184,3185,3187,3188,3189,3190,3191,3192,3193,3194,3196,3197,3410",
          "actions_nr" : 41,
          "city" : "Ahmadabad City",
          "citylink" : "<a href=\"/data/report/commitments/?tx_datareport_pi1%5Buid%5D=549\" target=\"_blank\" >Ahmadabad City</a>",
          "commitments" : "816",
          "commitments_nr" : 1,
          "country" : "India",
          "latitude" : "23.0300",
          "longitude" : "72.5800",
          "performance" : "900,901",
          "performance_nr" : 2,
          "uid" : "549"
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

I keep getting string indices must be integers

```
json_file = source_json

with open(json_file) as json_file:

    json_data = json.load(json_file)

    for e in json_data: # iterator over a dictionary
        #print e
        for key, value in e.iteritems():
            if key != '_id':
                print key, value
                #city_climate_data['city'] = value['test.city']
                #print city_climate_data['city']
```

Comment: Could you please include the relevant part of the JSON input with your question?

Comment: could you cast the string into int?

Answer (score 1):

> I keep getting string indices must be integers

In [JSON](http://json.org/) a pair must be `string : value`. It is not possible to have an integer as `key`.

**Edit**

I've added a small sample of the JSON to your question. With this JSON, your code will not work because a dictionary does not have `iteritems`. You can do this:

```
for e in json_data:
    for k, v in e.items():
        if k != '_id':
            print k, v
```

That would give this output:

```
country, Japan
citylink, <a href="/data/report/commitments/?tx_datareport_pi1%5Buid%5D=198" target="_blank" >Adachi City</a>
commitments, 338,339
commitments_nr, 1
longitude, 139.482
performance_nr, 4
actions_nr, 0
latitude, 35.465
uid, 198
actions, None
performance, 355,356,1090,1091
city, Adachi City
test, [{'country': 'Japan', 'commitments': '338,339', 'citylink': '<a href="/data/report/commitments/?tx_datareport_pi1%5Buid%5D=198" target="_blank" >Adachi City</a>', 'commitments_nr': 1, 'longitude': '139.482', 'performance_nr': 4, 'actions_nr': 0, 'latitude': '35.465', 'uid': '198', 'actions': None, 'performance': '355,356,1090,1091', 'city': 'Adachi City'}, {'country': 'India', 'commitments': '816', 'citylink': '<a href="/data/report/commitments/?tx_datareport_pi1%5Buid%5D=549" target="_blank" >Ahmadabad City</a>', 'commitments_nr': 1, 'longitude': '72.5800', 'performance_nr': 2, 'actions_nr': 41, 'latitude': '23.0300', 'uid': '549', 'actions': '3025,3105,3106,3108,3109,3110,3111,3112,3113,3114,3115,3116,3164,3166,3167,3168,3170,3171,3172,3173,3174,3175,3176,3177,3180,3181,3182,3183,3184,3185,3187,3188,3189,3190,3191,3192,3193,3194,3196,3197,3410', 'performance': '900,901', 'city': 'Ahmadabad City'}]
```

What part of the JSON are you interested in?

Comment: The format of the json is   {u'city': u'Zapopan', u'performance_nr': 1, u'uid': u'349', u'commitments_nr': 3, u'country': u'Mexico', u'commitments': u'859,860,861', u'actions': u'3743', u'longitude': u'-103.50208', u'citylink': u'<a href="/data/report/commitments/?tx_datareport_pi1%5Buid%5D=349" target="_blank" >Zapopan</a>', u'latitude': u'20.79803', u'performance': u'941', u'actions_nr': 1},

Comment: Please edit your question and include the JSON there.

Comment: Just to clarify that when you run the code above it dumps {u'city': u'Zihuatanejo, Guerrero', u'performance_nr': 0, u'uid': u'553', u'commitments_nr': 0, u'country': u'Mexico', u'commitments': None, u'actions': None, u'longitude': u'-101.553073', u'citylink': u'<a href="/data/report/commitments/?tx_datareport_pi1%5Buid%5D=553" target="_blank" >Zihuatanejo, Guerrero</a>', u'latitude': u'17.644315', u'performance': None, u'actions_nr': 0}

Comment: I am sorry but your comment does not clarify anything for me. Your code does not work with the JSON you linked to.